# Dataset of Russian handwriting characters

Tags: computer-vision, dataset, mnist

I'm working on a Russian handwriting character recognition. For example, I have a picture of some letter and my system should recognize most of the symbols on this picture. I have a problem with datasets for recognition. I found some datasets for English handwriting symbols like [this one](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Letter+Recognition). My question is: Where can I find datasets of Russian handwriting symbols because I failed to google it?

Answer (score 1):

Datasets of Cyrillic handwriting characters:

1. https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B0EQUc5HmgcGS0l2RDlKenlpNnc&usp=sharing
2. https://github.com/GregVial/CoMNIST (see Russian version, only uppercase letters)

Also, there are several datasets for the task of handwriting text recognition (not character).

1. This dataset contains Russian words https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/constantinwerner/cyrillic-handwriting-dataset
2. This dataset contains Kazakh and Russian words https://github.com/abdoelsayed2016/HKR_Dataset